# how to show following is totally disconnected?

Tags: banach-algebras

We know that $l_{\infty}$ be banach algebra ( under pointwise multiplication  and with sup  norm). How to show that its maximal ideals space is totally disconnected?

Comment: ???? Ideal $\implies$ vector subspace $\implies$ arc connected. I'm losing something?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla. The maximal ideals are points in a space S. The Q is about the topology of S.